# proto.007-PsDELPH1.storage_exhausted.operation when originating contract (storage_limit is set)

Tags: smart-contracts, ligo, truffle

I am trying to deploy a contract to delphinet with truffle.
On a local sandbox the contract deploys just fine, but for the deployment on Delphi I am getting:

```
 proto.007-PsDELPH1.storage_exhausted.operation
```

when I run

```
truffle migrate --network delphinet
```

So after some digging I found https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/PROTO_003_FEES.md. Therefore I set the parameters accordingly(?) for the deployer:

```
deployer.deploy(TestContract, storage).send({storage_limit: 257, gas_limit: 10000, opbytes: 185, fee:1285});
```

Now this still fails with the same error.

```
"TestContract" -- (temporary) proto.007-PsDELPH1.storage_exhausted.operation.
```

Can anybody spot my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with Ligo / truffle, but the process for injecting operations on Tezos is not just to hardcode numbers. There are many cases, related to the network that will cause additional burn fees, higher storage requirements, additional required gas etc. For example, if this is the first time working on delphinet, the source account might not be revealed, which would need another 257 storage. Also note that the link you pointed to, is over 2 years old, and out of date.

My experience is only with using the Tezos RPC, but the process might be able to help you figure out how to do it in Ligo/truffle. Using the Tezos RPC, the idea is to "simulate" the operation using the the `.../run_operation` endpoint. This then returns all the required gas, burn, storage requirements etc. Then you take these figures and use them to decide what numbers to put into your operation.

I wrote a series of tutorials walking through all these steps, using the CLI and the application Postman, to let developers experiment with sending the requests and reviewing the results. Feel free to have a read of the estimating fees section:

https://gitlab.com/camlcase-dev/tezos-rpc-postman